# Sybase Features

Tags: user-defined-functions, common-table-expression, sap-ase

Does anybody know if Common Table Expressions and User-defined functions (not from Java) are supported on Sybase 12.5? I'm trying but could not seem to make these work. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm referring to Sybase ASE 12.5

Comment: There is some info in related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803573/does-sybase-ase-12-5-support-common-table-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Both are not supported by ASE 12.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedure instead of functions. I am not sure about what you are referring to by saying common table expressions

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have to disagree.  Microsoft SQL Server is based on Sybase 7.0.  So there may not be Common Table Expressions and User-Defined Functions, there are equivalent ways to do the same thing.

For example CTE can be done either in nested queries or via temp tables using a number sign (#) in front of the table name.

For User Defined Functions, create a stored procedure with simple SQL code and call it via  the exec function for example "exec my_sql_code".  This allows nesting of stored procedures.

Good SQL, good night.

Comment: We are talking about 'feature' availability. What you've mentioned are workarounds.